# add jquery file if a certain page is included

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was wondering if anyone could help me by explaining if it is possible to enqueue a javascript file only if for example homepage.php is included.

what i have tried to do inside homepage.php:

```
class homepage_js {
static $add_script;

static function init() {
    add_action('init', array(__CLASS__, 'register_script'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array(__CLASS__, 'print_script'));
}

static function register_script() {
    wp_register_script('my-script', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

static function print_script() {
    if ( ! self::$add_script )
        return;

    wp_print_scripts('my-script');
}
}

homepage_js::init();
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your wordpress home page you can do this in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , my_enqueue_scripts );
function my_enqueue_scripts(){
    if ( is_home() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( ... ); 
    }
}
```